# How to get notification when upload has started and when it has finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I need to know if there's a way to get a notification from AWS S3 when the upload has started.

As of now I've set up aws lambda which notifies my backend when the PUT operation is finished, but I have no way to know when it has started (if it has started at all). This is required because my goroutine waits for the upload to be finished but I have no way to know when it has started, I could put a timeout on the goroutine but it would be tricky for large files and slow internet connections of clients because my backend would consider the operation failed when in reality the client might still be uploading the file.

Comment: Can you provide some context, code, or any additional details? It's not clear what you're trying to do or why you would need your Go code to get a notification when an upload is initiated.

Comment: I didn't think it mattered since all I've asked is in the first line of the question, is there a way to know when the upload has started and when has it finished on AWS?

Comment: OK, but you've already stated that you're getting notifications when it finishes, so yes, obviously there's a way to be notified when it's finished. I'm not aware of any way to be notified by S3 when an upload is started, but again, context could be helpful here, as it is with most technical questions.

Comment: the client sends a request to the backend to upload files, the backend replies with an AWS presigned url for upload, then waits for the upload to be completed through this presigned url, my problem is that the waiting goroutine stands waiting for the upload to be completed and might stand there forever on failure, i could set a timeout for the goroutine but then i have no way to know if the client is still uploading (large files, slow internet etc) or has failed to upload or never used the url.

Comment: maybe there is a way to be notified when the said presigned url has expired then i could tell the goroutine to quit on that event.

Comment: Why does the goroutine wait at all? I would think the more straightforward design would be to issue the URL and finish, and allow a separate listener to get the notification that an upload was completed. There's no reason to have one routine do both and wait in between. If you feel you really must wait, just use a timeout to stop waiting when business logic determines it's safe to assume the upload isn't going to happen.

Comment: Honestly, separating the URL generation from the upload completion has numerous benefits - e.g. what if you have to restart your service while an upload is in progress? What if you have to scale out and run multiple instances of the service, and the one that issued the upload URL isn't the one that gets the completion notification for it? What if you have two uploads going at once?

Comment: You are indeed right, my idea was to finish the operation using one api endpoint while in reality having the operation split in two endpoints, one in which you require the presigned urls to upload and the other one in which you confirm that the upload is finished seems like a better way to do things.

As for why I set the goroutine to wait is because the backend has some more stuff to do that can be done only if the upload is succesful.

Comment: Then it can do that in response to the upload completion notification you're already getting - there's no reason for the logic that creates the URL to wait at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **AWS CloudWatch rule** for S3 by specifying *Simple Storage Service (S3)* as Service Name, *Object Level Operations* as Event Type, *PutObject* as Specific operation(s) and  as Specific bucket(s) by name after creating a trail in **AWS CloudTrail** for S3's *PutObject* operation and specifying your desired target, for example, AWS Lambda function or AWS SNS topic to record the start time of an object upload on AWS S3 bucket.

As soon as the **PutObject API operation** (someone uploads an object) will be performed, it will be **recorded in AWS CloudTrail** if the trail is created already.

Note: You can also use *CreateMultipartUpload* or *UploadPart* as Specific operation(s) if required.